# programmatically reading the datatype of a property

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

```xml
...
...
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#fileName">
    <rdfs:label>fileName</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Name of File</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#File"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>


<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#fileLastAccessed">
    <rdfs:label>fileLastAccessed</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment>Time when the file was last accessed.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#File"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;dateTime"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
...
...
```

Above is a portion of the ontology that I have developed in protege.

You can see that datatype of the `#fileName` properties is `&xsd;string` and datatype of `#fileLastAccessed` is `&xsd;dateTime`

I am developing an application in which I would need to programmatically read the datatype of a property.

My question is that how would I know programmatically the datatype of a property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jena api get range of ObjectProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250198/jena-api-get-range-of-objectproperty).  That question specifically asks about object properties, but the same code works for data properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you demonstrate in your example ontology, the range of a property is specified by the `rdfs:range` value on a `rdf:Property`/`owl:DatatypeProperty` instance.

Assuming that you had a Jena `Model` that contained the data in your example:

```java
final Property fileName = model.getResource("http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#fileName")
                               .as(Property.class);
final StmtIterator definedRanges = fileName.listProperties(RDFS.range)
```

In the previous code, `definedRanges` will be an iterator that is empty if no ranges were defined. If it is non-empty, it should indicate the range of your property. If your property is a `owl:DatatypeProperty`, then you *should* be safe assuming that it's specifying a literal datatype.

Comment: You can listProperties(RDFS.range) here, but you could also use OntProperty#listRange(), as illustrated in [jena api get range of ObjectProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24250198/1281433) (the title says Object Property, but it should work with data properties too).

Comment: That was exactly I needed, I further added below code to exactly extracct what I want 
 
`for (; definedRanges.hasNext(); ) 
         {
          Statement stmt = definedRanges.next();
             Property p2 =  stmt.getPredicate();
             RDFNode o2 = stmt.getObject(); ...`